# Kendo Angular Bar chart customization on applying gradient color

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

[image]iam new to Kendo UI angular,
i have to customize a bar chart, where every bar will have multiple color gradient.
is it possible to attain in kendo? i have my bar chart developed in fusion but iam finding it little difficult to acheive the same with kendo.

have attached an image of what i need to achieve and also what my code in kendo is.

my code in kendo

```
<kendo-chart style="height: 317px;">
    <kendo-chart-axis-defaults [majorGridLines]="{ visible : false}">
      </kendo-chart-axis-defaults>
      <kendo-chart-series-defaults type="bar">
          <kendo-chart-series-defaults-labels format="">
          </kendo-chart-series-defaults-labels>
      </kendo-chart-series-defaults>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis >
        <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','aug','set','oct','nov','dec']">
        </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
    </kendo-chart-category-axis>
  <kendo-chart-series>                  
      <kendo-chart-value-axis>
          <kendo-chart-value-axis-item [line]="{visible:false}" labels="false">
          </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
      </kendo-chart-value-axis>
    <kendo-chart-series-item 
      type="column"
      [color]="pointColor"
      [gap]="10"
      [stack]="true" 
      [data]="['1000','0','200','2000','1500','1000','0','200','2000','1500','3500','25']"
      >
      <kendo-chart-series-item-labels [content]="labelContent" rotation="90" [position]="end" >
        </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
    </kendo-chart-series-item>
  </kendo-chart-series>
</kendo-chart>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a gradient effect you can use the series property [overlay](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/Overlay/).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-chart>
      <kendo-chart-title text="Units sold"></kendo-chart-title>
      <kendo-chart-category-axis>
          <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']">
          </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
      </kendo-chart-category-axis>
      <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="bar" [gap]="2" [spacing]=".25" [data]="[100, 123, 234, 343]" [overlay]="{gradient: 'roundedBevel'}">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="bar" [data]="[120, 67, 231, 196]" [overlay]="{gradient: 'glass'}" >
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="bar" [data]="[45, 124, 189, 143]" [overlay]="{gradient: 'none'}">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="bar" [data]="[87, 154, 210, 215]" [overlay]="{gradient: 'sharpBevel'}">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
      </kendo-chart-series>
    </kendo-chart>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Also came across this [demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/convertion-jquery-charts/), for creating custom linear gradients. Please refer to code below I have created a linear gradient column chart as an example.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Surface, Path, Text, Group, Layout, LinearGradient, GradientOptions, ShapeOptions } from '@progress/kendo-drawing';
import { Arc as DrawingArc, GradientStop } from '@progress/kendo-drawing';
import { Arc, Rect, ArcOptions } from '@progress/kendo-drawing/geometry';
function createColumn(rect, color) {
            const origin = rect.origin;
            const bottomRight = rect.bottomRight();
            const gradient = new LinearGradient(<GradientOptions>{
                stops: [new GradientStop(0, "#98FB98", 1),
                        new GradientStop(0.5, color, 1)]
            });

              const path = Path.fromRect(rect, <ShapeOptions>{
                    fill: gradient,
                    stroke: {
                        color: color,
                        width: 1
                    }
                });

            const group = new Group();
            group.append(path);
            return group;
        }

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-chart [seriesDefaults]="chartConfig.seriesDefaults" >
      <kendo-chart-title text="Units sold"></kendo-chart-title>
      <kendo-chart-category-axis>
          <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']">
          </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
      </kendo-chart-category-axis>
      <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="bar" [gap]="2" [spacing]=".25" [data]="[100, 123, 234, 343]" color="#008852">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
      </kendo-chart-series>
    </kendo-chart>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
public chartConfig = {
      seriesDefaults: {
          type: 'column',
          visual: function (e) {
              return createColumn(e.rect, e.options.color);
          }
      }
  };

}
```

Comment: how do we mention the custom colors that we have to use in [overlay]

Comment: @Arun I have updated my answer please check the code for linear gradient columns.

Comment: i noticed this works fine with bar chart as it is horixzontal but for column chart the gradient doesnt apply from top to bottom or bottom to top.
tried with radialGradient, but was not the exact output that i could achieve

Comment: can we move the label of the chart like how it is in the above image using drawing library, i tried but couldnt get through!

Comment: @arunkumar suggested an approach above in javascript you can look at the angular equivalent

Comment: @arunkumar please look at my latest edit and let me know if it was close to what you intend to do

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem as @arunkumar described. Your example works fine for Bar charts, but not for Column charts. The gradient is set from left to right, while it should be top to bottom for columns. Any idea on how to set the orientation?

Comment: @arunkumar To set the orientation from top to bottom set the 'start' and the 'end' of the gradient like this:
`gradient.start([0.5, 0]);
gradient.end([0.5, 1]);`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your chart I feel like it can be achieved by a [100% stacked column chart](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/bar-charts/grouped-stacked100-bar) you can get the data for both colored and grayed out portions. 
Then use a label property which can be displayed and with [rotation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/configuration/series.labels.rotation).

```
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [ {
    labels: {
      visible: true,
      position: "outsideEnd",
      rotation: 270 
    },
    data: [1, 2, 3]
  }]
});
</script>
```

Tried to get a similar look for the bar chart using radial gradient and 100% stacked bars

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Surface, Path, Text, Group, Layout, LinearGradient, RadialGradient, GradientOptions, ShapeOptions } from '@progress/kendo-drawing';
import { Arc as DrawingArc, GradientStop } from '@progress/kendo-drawing';
import { Arc, Rect, ArcOptions } from '@progress/kendo-drawing/geometry';
function createColumn(rect, color) {
            const origin = rect.origin;
            const bottomRight = rect.bottomRight();

            const radialgradient = new RadialGradient(<GradientOptions>{
               center:[0.5, 0],
                stops: [new GradientStop(0.5, color, 1),
                        new GradientStop(1, "#98FB98", 1)]
            });

            const path = Path.fromRect(rect, <ShapeOptions>{
                    fill: radialgradient,
                    stroke: {
                        color: color,
                        width: 1
                    }
                });

              const path1 = Path.fromRect(rect, <ShapeOptions>{
                    fill: {color: color},
                    stroke: {
                        color: color,
                        width: 1
                    }
                });

            const group = new Group();
            if(color == "#eee"){
                group.append(path1);
            }
            else{
                group.append(path);
            }

            return group;
        }

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-chart [seriesDefaults]="chartConfig.seriesDefaults" >
      <kendo-chart-title text="Units sold"></kendo-chart-title>
      <kendo-chart-category-axis>
          <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [categories]="['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']">
          </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
      </kendo-chart-category-axis>
      <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item type="column" [stack]="{ type: '100%' }" [gap]="2" [spacing]=".25" [data]="[100, 120, 250, 345]" color="#008852">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
         <kendo-chart-series-item type="column" [data]="[400, 380, 250, 155]" color="#eee">
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
      </kendo-chart-series>
    </kendo-chart>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
public chartConfig = {
      seriesDefaults: {
          visual: function (e) {
              return createColumn(e.rect, e.options.color);
          }
      }
  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that they expose hooks that allows you to control how each bar is rendered. Using the `seriesDefaults` property on kendo-chart, you can provide your own `visual()` method.
Steps:

1. In your template, bind to seriesDefaults:

```
<kendo-chart [seriesDefaults]="seriesDefaults"></kendo-chart>
```

2. In your component, provide a custom visual method on seriesDefaults:

```
    seriesDefaults: SeriesDefaults = {
            type: 'column',
            visual: (e: SeriesVisualArgs) => createColumn(e.rect, e.options.color, e.dataItem),
        };
```

3. The custom method could look something like this. Optionally I added a text item above each bar to show the dataItem value (it's rough, I'm making assumptions about it's x/y position):

````
export function createColumn(rect: geometry.Rect, color: string, dataItem: number): Group {
        const gradient = new LinearGradient(<GradientOptions>{
            stops: [new GradientStop(0, color, 0.7), new GradientStop(0.4, color, 1)],
        });
        gradient.start([0.5, 0]);
        gradient.end([0.5, 1]);
    
        // Turn the rect into a path and reference the gradient
        const path = Path.fromRect(rect, <ShapeOptions>{
            fill: gradient,
            stroke: {
                color: '#777',
                width: 1,
            },
        });
    
        // Add the dataItem value above the bar
        const position = rect.topLeft();
        position.y -= 13;
        position.x += (rect.width() / 2) - 10;
        const text = new Text(dataItem + '', position);
    
        const group = new Group();
        group.append(path);
        group.append(text);
        return group;
    }
    ```

[![Results][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVOmQ.png
````